# How to fetch last inserted record for particular id?

Tags: django, django-views

Apologies, I am completely new to `Django`. My question is that I have 20 records in my database table and suppose 10 record is of same ID and I want to fetch last inserted record for that id I have date column in my table. How can I do that?

Comment: You need to give more details. Usually IDs are unique, so you can't have ten records for an ID.

Comment: duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31070368/django-get-latest-entry-from-database

Comment: sorry its not Id its is user_id,i have 10 records for same user_id

Comment: You should create an [mcve] and read [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
last_obj = YourModel.objects.last()
```

But generally, you can't create > 1 objects with same id, if you didn't specified your own id field to replace built-in. And even then, it's a bad idea.

Comment: "sorry its not Id its is user_id,i have 10 records for smae user_id"

Comment: Then it's like
`YourModel.objects.filter(user_id=your_id).last()`
Optionally, you can .filter().order_by('field_name')

But better read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/