# Django: get latest database object values after submitted form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a form that saves three input-values to a database, 1) number, 2) color, 3) make.
After I press "submit" another routine should immediately display those values.

Problem is that I cannot get latest values to display but instead, once the values have been initially assigned, they do not update and sticks to the first assigned values.

Trying to solve it, posts suggests to update the object, such as [Django Get Latest Entry from Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31070368/django-get-latest-entry-from-database),  I created a function which I called upon within view after pressing submit, but without luck.

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.views.generic import FormView
from django.urls import path, include
from django.urls import reverse


class Product(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    make = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    objects = models.Manager()

class ProductModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('__all__')


def database():
    dbo = Product.objects.latest('id')
    dbo.refresh_from_db()
    return dbo


class ProductFormView(FormView):
    form_class = ProductModelForm
    template_name = 'form/test_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        database()
        print(Product.objects.latest('id'))  # just as a test
        return reverse('product')



urlpatterns = [
    path('', ProductFormView.as_view(), name='product'),
]

# <!DOCTYPE html>
# <html lang="en">
# <head>
#     <meta charset="UTF-8">
#     <title>Title</title>
# </head>
# <body>
# <form method="post" >
#     {% csrf_token %}
#     {{form}}
#     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
# </form>
# </body>
# </html>
```

I have a simple routine (db_connector.py) I create a linkage between a database object and variables, such as (without any function or class):

```
number = database().number
color = database().color
make = database().make
```

This is perhaps wrong way of doing it, but reflect an (perhaps naive) attempt to minimize database requests, with the ideas to request one object and then split this object into parts and link to the parts.

**Problem is:**

- I update all values in the form and press submit (which works) and this latest entry is now on "top" of the database. I want to retrieve this object (latest input values of 'number', 'color', and 'make'. However, instead of giving me this object, I get an earlier object. Despite trying to "refresh" the linked object (Product.objects.latest('id')) it is stuck with an earlier input (the first input).

**Question is:**

- How should I do, to always get the latest input values once I press submit on my form (with updated values)?

Comment: Hi, did you try: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.refresh_from_db?

Comment: Please post the minimal code needed to reproduce this issue - and specially the part where you "create a linkage between a database object and variables". Note that if you're using global variables, it's never going to work properly.

Comment: Hi Bruno, thanks for taking time to answer. I have updated the code. I need some time to go through your answer. In the meanwhile, if you see that my updated code would enable to detail your answer differently, please update. Let me come back to you, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a form that saves three input-values to a database, 1) number,
>   2) color, 3) make. After I press "submit" another routine should
>   immediately display those values.
>
> Problem is that I cannot get latest values to display

Your doing it wrong (and much more complicated than it has to be). The proper solution is to explicitely pass the product's id to your "product" view (via the url), and load the object afresh in the view (using `yourmodel.objects.get(pk=...)`). If you're using a model form to create your record, `form.save()` returns the new record so you *do* have the id at this point (and if you only update an existing product, then you obviously know the id already).

You didn't post enough code / informations to technically explain why you have this behaviour but I strongly suspect you're using global variables (or class attributes), which is the most common cause of stale data in Django projects.

Also, note that calling "refresh_from_db()" on a model instance you just fetched from db is mainly useless (chances it gets updated between those two calls are rather slim), and that given how your (ill-named) "database" function is implemented, this:

```
number = database().number
color = database().color
make = database().make
```

ends up making **six** (**6**) queries to the database.

Comment: Thanks, I have stripped away and only keep 
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

then I use success_url = reverse_lazy('product'). All this should produce the same result, if I read it correct using form.save()

My core problem/what I want to achieve is to link a list of variables to the most recent database record. You warn against global variables, but what is then the "correct" solution? For completeness, I use these values to populate a pdf and the reverse is simple a get request to activate the pdf production (no html).

Comment: As I already mentionned, the right thing to do is to rewrite your "product" view (and matching url) so that it takes a product id as parameter and use `Product.objects.get(pk=your_product_id)` to load the matching product - and of course in the form view's `get_success_url` pass the newly created product's id to `reverse()`. That's the standard, canonical way to do things.

Answer (score 1):

Although the code you provided isn't enough imo, I'll try to help and explain.

Based on my understanding (have never used `refresh_from_db`), you cannot use `refresh_from_db` this way.

In your `database()` function you get the last entry and you try to refresh its information, though you haven't changed it since getting it, making it a pointless line (it does not refresh the query, but the instance returned as a result).

`refresh_from_db()` updates a specific instance information if you have changed it between getting it from the database and using it.

As per the example from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.refresh_from_db):

```
def test_update_result(self):
    obj = MyModel.objects.create(val=1)
    MyModel.objects.filter(pk=obj.pk).update(val=F('val') + 1)
    # At this point obj.val is still 1, but the value in the database
    # was updated to 2. The object's updated value needs to be reloaded
    # from the database.
    obj.refresh_from_db()
    self.assertEqual(obj.val, 2)
```

It simply does not do what you think it does.

Your submit button is supposed to call a post method in the relative class view, or some function that saves those values into the database (you also mentioned it yourself).
In your reversed view function or class you can write the query you wrote in `datebase()` - `Product.objects.latest('id')`.

Also, you can reverse with added information such as this: `return reverse('product', kwargs={'lastprod': Product.objects.latest('id')})`.

Let me know if this isn't clear enough.